Group Action of GL(2,Q) on Irrational Numbers
I am recently considering the action of the general linear group over rational number, $GL(2,\mathbb{Q})$ on the irrational numbers defined as in this link.
For the same action of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, there is a complete characterization. However, I failed to do the same thing to that of $GL(2,\mathbb{Q})$.
Please tell me if anyone know where I can get some information about this action.

What do you mean by "complete characterization"? Can you provide this for $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

What I am concerned about is when two irrational numbers are equivalent, i.e, they are in the same orbit of the action. By the analysis in the book of Hardy and Wright about number theory, the action of a matrix in $GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ on an irrational number is just the same as changing finitely many terms of the continued fraction representation of this irrational number.

In another word, two irrational numbers are in the same orbit of the action of $GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ iff their continued fraction representations are tail equivalent, i.e., if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are the representations, then there are $i,j$ such that for all $k$, $a_{i+k}=b_{j+k}$. However, this analysis relies on that the matrix is a integer matrix and the determinant of the matrix is 1 or -1.
